# Are my Jenkins builds checkouts from my SCM?

Tags: php, git, jenkins, continuous-integration, composer-php

Trying to understand this [CI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) thing so I've downloaded [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) in my production server...

**1. Is Jenkins (or any other CI system) installed in the production server or I should have a separate server for Jenkins builds?**
*If Jenkins is in another server, how can I integrate the builds as my running production code? Or this CI thing does have nothing to do with deploys?*

Then I created a SSH key at /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh added to my [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) ([Git](http://git-scm.com/)) repository as Deployment key...

**2. Is this the correct approach?**

...And set the repository URL `git@bitbucket.org:...` with `jenkins` user credentials in the Git plugin at project settings.
So far so good, my build checkout the project to the Jenkins workspace, then I noticed that every build it run is a checkout and for every checkout, as a [Composer](http://getbootstrap.com/) powered project, my `vendors/` directory isn't there, so I don't have the `autoload.php` file that `phpunit.xml` uses as bootstrap to load the classes and run the tests. So besides `phpunit` as one of the build shell commands I've added `composer init`.

**3. Is this right? Should I run `composer init` on every build?**

The main question maybe is: are my builds constructed from greenfield space? Should I checkout and run `composer install` and whatever scripts my project must take to be running every time (every build)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is Jenkins (or any other CI system) installed in the production server or I should have a separate server for Jenkins builds? If Jenkins is in another server, how can I integrate the builds as my running production code? Or this CI thing does have nothing to do with deploys?
>
> Then I created a SSH key at /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh added to my Bitbucket >(Git) repository as Deployment key...
>
> 2. Is this the correct approach?

That's correct. I have a bunch of servers configured this way. In the near future I want investigate if it would be possible to use the [SSH Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Credentials+Plugin) to store my credentials there, so that I don't have to take care with the file system permissions for that key.

> 3. Is this right? Should I run composer init on every build?
>
> The main question maybe is: are my builds constructed from greenfield space? Should I checkout and run composer install and whatever scripts my project must take to be running every time (every build)?

It depends on your requirements. You can have several builds, or parametrize you build to support different behaviours. For instance, I have Laravel builds that depending on the environment parameter, they might do further testing with Selenium, or simply run phpunit.

I usually have two projects in Jenkins for each PHP application. One that checks out the code from git, clean any left-over of other builds in the workspace, and invokes Laravel's Envoy for building the project. What it basically does, is call `composer install` with some extra parameters, and call the migration and database seed routines to prepare the application for testing.

The other job is triggered when I promote (with Jenkins Promoted Builds Plugin) a build, and it copies (with the [Copy Artifacts Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin)) the workspace created during build and already tested, and deploys it via scp to a folder in a QA server. It then updates some symbolic links, and finally it's ready to test.

With time and more requirements from developers and other teams, you'll get familiar with many other plug-ins, like the [Email-ext Plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin), to send custom notifications and include further information about the build.

Comment: Okay, so there is no rule for what my builds are, right? If a told Jenkins that a build is just a `git pull` instead of a `git checkout`, there is no problem if that? Its better to have separate jobs for testing and deploying? Thats why you have two Jenkins projects for each PHP project?

Comment: > *Is Jenkins (or any other CI system) installed in the production server or I should have a separate server for Jenkins builds?*

You should **definitely** use a separate server for CI, not an actual **production** server!

Comment: Leo, you will probably want to use Git Plugin and configure it to try to merge the changes, or always clone a clean repository. As for one or several jobs, I find it easier to create and manage build pipelines that way, but it is up to you and your team to choose what will work better for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Best practices would dictate a separate VM for Jenkins, just to keep it apart from other environments that it might deploy TO.

Jenkins can take down other services using scripts, so taking down the same tomcat running Jenkins that you are deploying a project to would be... inconvenient.

I fall into the camp that favors multiple Jenkins jobs that are chained together.  One job builds.  Another tests. and a third deploys.  That way you know exactly which job is problematic.  You can also look at job run times and get a better picture of what is taking so long (is it deploy?  is it the unit tests?) and troubleshoot the problems from a higher POV.

I have a Jenkins Best Practices presentation I gave at the Boise Code Camp 2015 available here:
http://lanyrd.com/2015/boise-code-camp/sdkggb/